# HTTP/1/1 400 Bad Request in a keep alive connection using sockets

Tags: http, tcp

Hi I am getting this error from the server. This is a TCP socket connection to an external IP using a tunnel. From our source IP we send a request to the destination server IP, port. This is the information provided to us on how to connect.

1. Your software opens a socket from your client platform to connect our server platform.

   2. Our server will respond by starting the “keep alive” dialog.
   3. Your software will send an X12 transmission packet with a single eligibility request.
   4. Our server will check the recipient’s information and send a response to allow or reject the eligibility

This is my client code to connect, send, receive to and from messages.  I am not sure about one thing. The way I am doing the HTTP Post.
They gave us a sample request. This is how it looks like

```
POST /OKMMISPOS HTTP/5.1
Content-Length: 521

ISA*00*__________*00*__________*ZZ*500000330______*ZZ*731476619______*090303*1414*U*004
```

--------------This is the X12 Content of the message-------------------------------------

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //create a new client socket ...
                string szIPSelected = "127.0.0.1";
                int szPort = 57000;
                if (textBox1.Text != "")
                    szIPSelected = textBox1.Text;
                if (textBox2.Text != "")
                    szPort = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                m_socClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);


                System.Net.IPAddress remoteIPAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(szIPSelected);
                System.Net.IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(remoteIPAddress, szPort);
                m_socClient.Connect(remoteEndPoint);
                if (m_socClient.Connected)
                {
                    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Connected to " + szIPSelected + ":" + szPort;
                    statusStrip1.Refresh();
                    SendRequest(m_socClient);
                    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Sending  Request to  " + szIPSelected + ":" + szPort;
                    statusStrip1.Refresh();
                }
                Thread.Sleep(3000);

                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRec = m_socClient.Receive(bytes);
                txtResponse271.Text =
                       Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);


            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
            }

        }
        private void SendRequest(Socket m_socClient)
        {

            string resource = "/OKMMISPOS";
            var header = String.Format("POST {0} HTTP/1.1\r\n", resource);
            String body = Query270;
            byte[] bodyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);
            header += "Content-Length: " + (body.Length + 1)+ "\r\n" + "\r\n";
            string request = String.Concat(header,body);
            textBox3.Text = request;
            textBox3.Refresh();
            byte[] requestBytes= Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);
            m_socClient.Send(requestBytes);
        }
```

My code sends a request similar to their but  I am getting a HTTP 400 bad request. On wireshark, the request starts out using TCP protocol. This is the screenshot from wireshark. HTTP 400. 
Also not sure if this is imp, the request starts out with TCP and the response comes back as HTTP 
Request
[image]

Response
[image]

Comment: Yes they've asked for that HTTP 5.1. So I have this string hardcoded. Please see SendRequest(socket) method. Query270 is a simple string. like this ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*500000355      *ZZ*734476619      *130716*2207*^*00501*577840582*0*T*:~GS*HS*500000355*734476619*20130716*2207*088605*X*005010X279A1~ST*270*0001*005010X279A1~BHT*0022*13*635096092580180604*20130716*

Comment: Your SendRequest(socket) method currently uses "HTTP/1.1". Requiring "5.1" is a really terrible architecture, as proxies will often barf on this. Also, note that real web-servers require a HOST header.

Comment: Host header might be the problem. Am I correct in assigning the required header(POST /OKMMISPOS HTTP/5.1
Content-Length: bodybytes.length) to a variable and concatenating the Body. Or should I be using a HTTPWebrequest class?.  So the final string 'request' will look like this POST /OKMMISPOS HTTP/5.1 
Content-Length: bodybytes.length/r/n/r/n <Body ISA string>

Comment: I have edited the screenshot. That is the response from server

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33602/discussion-between-ericlaw-and-user575219)

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to their server and not attempting to use any kind of proxy?